# Sending one of multiple forms with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, click, element

I'm doing a thing like the follow-:

```
$.each(data2, function(key2, val2) {
    $('#posts').append('<div class="send_comment" align="right">');
    $('#posts').append('<input type="hidden" class="com_post_id" value="'+i+'"><br /\>');
    $('#posts').append('Author: <input type="text" class="com_author"><br /\>');
    $('#posts').append('Img: <input type="text" class="com_img"><br /\>');
    $('#posts').append('Text: <input type="text" class="com_text"><br /\>');
    $('#posts').append('<button class="new_comment">Send</button>');
    $('#posts').append('</div>');
});
```

How can I send these fields with `$.post`? With `$(this)`, I can get the clicked element, but then?

Comment: do you need to send it after an event, like click? You can use json to send the data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is dynamically injected element,you should bind the functionality using `jQuery on`

```
  $(function(){
      $(".send_comment").on("click",".new_comment",function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var item=$(this);
         var postId=item.parent().find(".com_post_id");   
         var author=item.parent().find(".com_author");  
         var msg=item.parent().find(".com_text");  

         $.post("yourPage.php", { id : postId, author:author ,msg:msg },function(result){
             //do whatever with result
              alert(result);
         });

      });
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

jQuery `on` will work on current and future elements.

Comment: @GiovanniCapuano : Glad it waited for you.

Answer (score 0):

`data = $(this).closest('form').serialize()`

Comment: Make sure that fields have a `name` attribute, or you'll get an empty value!

Answer (score 0):

I always found the modal form example from jqueryui's site as a good example of how to send data from a form: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Essentially give your fields ids, then:

```
var author = $( "#author" ),
    image = $( "#image" ),
    text = $( "#text" ),
    allFields = $( [] ).add( author ).add( image ).add( text );
```

Then use post:

```
$.post("your_url_that_processes_data",allFields, function(data){ 
   // do something with data 
});
```

If you have multiple forms that vary slightly there are plenty of ways to go about that. I'd recommend either changing the action URL OR grabbing an "id" from some DOM element some how. Maybe you can change the form id to something like : `"form-".id` in your script then read it before you submit.

I can potentially try to help with a more detailed use case?

Comment: I have solved with the Shyju's solution, but thank you too for the yours.